# Java code doesn't see file over NFS mount

Tags: java, tomcat6, nfs

I am having an issue trying to troubleshoot some java (running in tomcat6) behavior with files over an NFS mount.  Here's an example of what I'm seeing in the code.

This message indicates that it's can't fine the file.

2014-07-23 02:20:33,537 INFO  [quartzScheduler_Worker-3] task.DoTranscodeJob - Dependency /mnt/nfs/accounts/23/assets/6/brain.mov does not exist, deferring. (has all deps: false)

However, I can see it at the OS level as the tomcat user with perms set to 777:

tomcat6@debian:/usr/local/logs$ ls -l /mnt/nfs/accounts/23/assets/6/brain.mov
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat6 tomcat6 46804903 Jul 23  2014 /mnt/nfs/accounts/23/assets/6/brain.mov

tomcat6@debian:/usr/local/logs$ stat /mnt/nfs/accounts/23/assets/6/brain.mov
  File: `/mnt/nfs/accounts/23/assets/6/brain.mov'
  Size: 46804903    Blocks: 91416      IO Block: 32768  regular file
Device: 12h/18d  Inode: 141849591006  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  102/ tomcat6)   Gid: (  104/ tomcat6)
Access: 2014-07-23 06:42:55.955233531 -0400
Modify: 2014-07-23 06:42:26.014772770 -0400
Change: 2014-07-23 09:32:25.131729679 -0400

tomcat6@debian:/usr/local/logs$ file  /mnt/nfs/accounts/23/assets/6/brain.mov
/mnt/nfs/accounts/23/assets/6/brain.mov: ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie

Any idea what would be causing this?

Here are my client/server NFS settings:

Client:

/mnt/nfs from 10.10.153.95:/share/Space
 Flags: rw,noatime,nodiratime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.10.153.95,mountvers=3,mountport=45704,mountproto=udp,addr=10.10.153.95

Server:

root@~# exportfs -v
/usr/local/nfsmount
        10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0(rw,async,wdelay,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

Can anyone suggest a way to help troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Check the owners & permissions of *all* directories in that path One of them might not allow for searching (the "x" bit). Also check that Tomcat doesn't have a SecurityManager; if there is one set, check that the web apps permissions allow it access to the file system outside of tomcat's directories.